# How to store a list in a text file?

Tags: python, json, list, merge

Hundreds of text files contain a list of tweets, and I am merging their contents into one large text file. But, the created file has this structure:

```
["[\"tweet.\", \"tweet.\", \"tweet.\"]", "[\"tweet.\", \"tweet.\", \"tweet.\"]", ... \"]"]
```

How can I adjust the structure like the following?

```
[["tweet","tweet","tweet"], ["tweet","tweet","tweet"], ...]
```

or, without any quotation and brackets:

```
tweet, tweet, tweet, tweet, ...
```

This is the code I wrote is as follows:

```
import json

# assign some paths and variables

merged_list = []
for doc in docs:
    f = open(text_file, "r")
    content = f.read()
    merged_list.append(content)
    f.close()

merged_text = 'merged_text.txt'
with open(merged_text, 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(merged_list))
```

Comment: try without `json.dumps` from `f.write(json.dumps(merged_list))`.

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia TypeError: write() argument must be str, not list

Comment: If you use `content = json.loads(f.read())`, it should parse the list properly.